# How can I suppress or disable temporal table history insertion for a single statement or transaction?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, temporal-tables

I have a table that stores Customer information (your bog-standard CRM stuff):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers (
    TenantId    int            NOT NULL,
    CustomerId  int            NOT NULL,
    
    FirstName   nvarchar(50)   NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    LastName    nvarchar(50)   NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    CompanyName nvarchar(50)   NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

    Notes       nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
```

This table was recently converted to be a SQL Server temporal table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers
    ADD COLUMN
        SysStart datetime2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
        SysEnd   datetime2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   NOT NULL;

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers WITH (
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ( SysStart, SysEnd ),
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Customers_History )
)
```

---

Since doing this, a problem has emerged: the user-facing form that users edit the Customer's details automatically saves the form contents 2 seconds after the last keystroke, and each save results in an `UPDATE` statement with incrementally increasing amounts of data - and so SQL Server is constantly adding new rows into the `Customers_History` table, 2 seconds apart, which results in spammy, low-information rows.

So this is what I see when I do a `SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers_History WHERE CustomerId = 123`, for example:

[image]

I was thinking that the server-side code that handles the auto-save submissions could check to see if the incoming form-state is an incremental change, and if so `UPDATE` the `dbo.Customers` table *without* adding any rows to the `Customers_History` table.

So far the only way [I can see to do this is by setting `SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) inside a transaction, however I have some questions before I actually implement this...

1. While the documentation says (even recommends) running `ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);` inside a transaction, **it doesn't say how this would affect other concurrent users and connections**. This is a DML statement after-all, and DML statements have inconsistent (hah!) behaviour w.r.t. isolation.
2. Starting and completing a transaction in a stored `PROCEDURE` or SQL batch is one thing - but determining if an `UPDATE` is actually incremental or not may require some custom application-code logic which then means having to start and commit the transaction from application-code, which seems like a bad idea because of the *thousands of things that could now go wrong*, not to mention performance issues (in this case, the network latency from the application server to the database-server should be less than 1ms, but that's still going to impact scalability).

---

Assuming I can do it in a `PROCEDURE`, is this code below *correct* and will it scale?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateSingleCustomerRow(
    @tenantId    int,
    @customerId  int,
    @firstName   nvarchar(50),
    @lastName    nvarchar(50),
    @companyName nvarchar(50),
    @notes       nvarchar(4000)
)

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION editCustomerTxn;

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Is it an incremental change?
    DECLARE @isIncremental bit = 0;

    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customers WHERE
        CustomerId = @customerId
        AND
        TenantId = @tenantId
        AND
        CHARINDEX( FirstName, @firstName ) > 0
        AND
        CHARINDEX( LastName, @lastName ) > 0
        AND
        CHARINDEX( CompanyName, @companyName ) > 0
        AND
        CHARINDEX( Notes, @notes ) > 0
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @isIncremental = 1;
    END

    -----------------------

    IF @isIncremental = 1
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
    END

    UPDATE
        dbo.Customers
    SET
        FirstName   = @firstName,
        LastName    = @lastName,
        CompanyName = @companyName,
        Notes       = @notes
    WHERE
        CustomerId = @customerId
        AND
        TenantId = @tenantId;
    
    IF @isIncremental = 1
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers SET (
            SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON(
                HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Customers_History
            )
        );
    END
    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION editCustomerTxn;

    RETURN 0;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION editCustomerTxn;
    END
    
    RETURN 1;

END CATCH
```

...but this doesn't *feel right* to me - because this is basically the same thing as hacking deferrable-constraints with `ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> running ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF); inside a transaction, it doesn't say how this would affect other concurrent users and connections.

ALTER TABLE always requires an exclusive schema lock (Sch-M). So no other session could read, update or alter the table until the transaction is committed or rolled back.

> is this code below correct and will it scale?

Won't scale.

So

> user-facing form that users edit the Customer's details automatically saves the form contents 2 seconds after the last keystroke, and each save results in an UPDATE statement

change that, or live with the verbose history table.  You can always run a batch job to delete some of the history rows (after turning SYSTEM_VERSIONING off in a transaction :)).

Comment: In the end, I decided to live with the excessive history rows (as temporal history tables use compression by default) - still, it's annoying when a nice new feature has gotchas like these. (Also, any word on when SQL Server will support Application-time instead of only `SYSTEM_TIME` like MariaDB does?)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a case where the application's behavior and the database feature just aren't a great fit. You could change your application's behavior so that incremental saves aren't made to this table so aggressively (perhaps caching saves more lazily elsewhere), or to not use temporal tables at all.

If you can't change the application behavior, then it would seem that this is an opportunity to use a trigger instead of a temporal table. The trigger could have logic to handle "intermediary saves" so that they obey a grace period to limit frequent saves.

[Stack Overflow & the Stack Exchange Network have a 5-minute grace period for edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/314146).

> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the revision history, a single user who edits a post is given a 5-minute [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info)...
> During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final outcome of all their edits within that 5 minute period.

Regardless of whether you implement the grace period for edit history at the application level, or at the database level, it'll definitely be a bit of coding on your part, as there's no database feature to automatically do this for you.

Comment: You're welcome to post a second question related to the other scenario not covered in this question. However, comments are intended for clarification, not for follow-ups or extended discussion.